# How I post and consume a Kafka message in the same IntegrationFlows builder

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-kafka, spring-integration-dsl

I want to do a simple kafka producer/consumer using spring integration, the way I did is separate in two builders each one like bean, but I wish do this just one @Bean

```
    @Bean
    fun myProducerFlow(kafkaTemplate: KafkaTemplate<*, *>): IntegrationFlow {

       return IntegrationFlows.from("testChannel")
                .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate)
                        .topic("channel1"))
                .get()
    }

    @Bean
    fun myConsumerFlow(consumerFactory: ConsumerFactory<*, *>): IntegrationFlow {

        return IntegrationFlows.from(Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(consumerFactory,"channel1"))
                .handle { message -> println(message) }
                .get()
    }
```

I wish something like this:

```
    @Bean
    fun myFlow(kafkaTemplate: KafkaTemplate<*, *>): IntegrationFlow {

       return IntegrationFlows.from("testChannel")
                .handle(Kafka.outboundChannelAdapter(kafkaTemplate)
                        .topic("channel1"))
         .channel(Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(consumerFactory,"channel1"))
                .handle { message -> println(message) }
                .get()
    }
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense; please elaborate and explain the problem.

Comment: Sorry, edited the way I expect my flow, I believe to be clearer

Comment: Basically want to post and consume a Kafka message in the same IntegrationFlows builder.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that; the message-driven adapter always starts a flow.

Answer (score 0):

This is two diffrents flow. use other way

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).